# Function to verify if an element present in an array

Tags: arrays, c

I am working in ADT of an Array and when doing a function to verify if an element is present in the array, it didn't work, actually, it just said the element 1 is present in the array, but it doesn't work with other integers elements of the array. The function is

```
int checkElement(Array *a, int elem){
    for (int i = 0; i < a->size; i++){
        if (a->array[i] == elem){
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Compilable code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct array{
    int size;
    int *array;
}Array;

Array* allocateMemory(int size){
    Array *a;

    a = (Array*) malloc(sizeof(Array));

    if (a == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    a->array = (int*) calloc(size, sizeof(int));

    if (a->array == NULL)
    {
       return NULL;
    }

    a->size = size;

    return a;
}

int add(Array *a, int elem, int c){
    if ((c > a->size) || (c < 0)){
        return 0;
    }
    a->array[c] = elem;
    return 1;
}

int print(Array *a, int c){
    return a->array[c];
}

int checkElement(Array *a, int elem){
    for (int i = 0; i < a->size; i++){
        if (a->array[i] == elem){
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Array *a1;
    a1 = allocateMemory(10);
    int elem = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (add(a1, elem, i)== 0)
        {
            printf("Something went wrong\n");
        }
        elem += 1;
    }
    printf("Array 1: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("\a[%d] = %d\n", i, print(a1, i));
    }

    int element = 6;
    int flag = checkElement(a1, element);
    if (flag == 1) printf("\nElement %d is present in the array", element);
    else printf("\nElement %d is not present in the array", element);


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 Array 1:
 [0] = 1
 [1] = 2
 .
 .
 .
 [9] = 10
 Element 2 is not present in the array
```

Comment: Well you only check the first element and return one way or the other. You can't return false until you've exhausted the entire array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int flag = checkElement(a1, element);`

```
int checkElement(Array *a, int elem){
for (int i = 0; i < a->size; i++){
    if (a->array[i] == elem){
        return 1;
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```